# How can I run a Java application based on Spark Framework, from a Vagrant virtual box?

Tags: java, webserver, jetty, vagrant, spark-java

By default, Java applications based on [Spark Framework](http://sparkjava.com) will run on its embedded [Jetty](http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/) server, on your host machine. However, if you use **Vagrant** as your virtualized development environment, this default Spark setup will obviously not work.

So, how can you run your Spark-based application from your Vagrant virtual box?

Comment: Thanks for you comment, Frederic. However, this GitHub post your shared is actually related to Apache Spark, as opposed to Spark Java micro-framework.

Comment: did you try at putting nginx in front as a load-balancer ? there are many examples how to setup nginx load balancing with vagrant

Comment: I think the solution I'm looking for is more along the lines of http://sparkjava.com/documentation.html#other-webserver (where another webserver would be hosted on a Vagrant guest machine).